# Why using round() instead of floor() may cause bug/(program error) in C?

Tags: c, debugging, buffer-overflow

I was debugging some code where I need to debug and fix bugs or possible errors. In one of the examples it was said `round()` may cause bug and fixed it with `floor()`. However, I didn't quite understand why.

Can anyone give prior example for that?

```
for (unsigned y = 0; y < round(factor * img->size_y); y++) { // round changed to floor
  for (unsigned x = 0; x < round(factor * img->size_x); x++) { // round changed to floor

    /* Calculate the location of the pixel in the old image */
    unsigned nearest_x = x / factor;
    unsigned nearest_y = y / factor;

    /* Store the pixel */
    image_data_new[y][x] = image_data[nearest_y][nearest_x];
  }
}
```

In above code `round()` replaced with `floor()` to avoid possible attack or bugs.

init code:

```
struct pixel(*image_data_new)[new_width] =
        (struct pixel(*)[new_width])new_img->px;
```

where new_width:

```
unsigned new_width = (unsigned)(img->size_x * factor);
double factor = atof(argv[3]);
```

Comment: because `round` can give a result which makes that `x` or `y` are 1-off out of max size of the array maybe. Show the initialization code of `image_data_new`. If you used `round` to compute its dimensions, then there's no problem

Comment: what do you mean by 1-off out of max size of the array?

Comment: There is a "bug" in that `unsigned nearest_x = x / factor;` does not find the _nearest_.  That would use `unsigned nearest_x = round(x / factor);`

Comment: Since new_width is casted to integer which is equal to floor(), maybe instead we would use unsigned nearest_x = floor(x / factor);   ?

Comment: @MarkEzberg `floor(x / factor)` same effect as `unsigned nearest_x = x / factor;` when the quotient is positive.  The point is: do you want the :"nearest" as implied with `nearest_x` or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your dimension seem to be

```
unsigned new_width = (unsigned)(img->size_x * factor);
```

casting to integer has the same effect as `floor` in that case.

Now you're using

```
for (unsigned x = 0; x < round(factor * img->size_x); x++)
```

that's really looking for trouble, as `round` is going to yield a value that can be more than `new_width` if the result to round decimal part is above `.5` (and can overflow the buffer). Just use the previously computed value:

```
for (unsigned x = 0; x < new_width; x++)
```

Answer (score 0):

If `round` rounds up, `nearest_y` can be equal to `img->size_y` which is greater than the dimension of the array it's being used to index.